# Lograr redireccionar a una pagina con su correspondiente id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Implementar este código para que funcione como debe de ser, al apretar el botón me dirija a una entrada correspondiente a esa id. mi idea fue esta pero esta claro que esta errónea.

```html
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Editar" 
onclick="location.href='@Html.ActionLink("EDITAR", "Details", new { id = item.PKDATOS })'">
  <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Editar" onclick="location.href='@Html.ActionLink("EDITAR", "Edit", new { id = item.PKDATOS })'">
  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Eliminar" onclick="location.href='@Html.ActionLink("ELIMINAR", "Delete", new { id = item.PKDATOS })'">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
  </button>
```

EL resultado que me da en el navegador es esta:

http://localhost:9860/%3Ca%20href=%22/Usuario/Delete/1%22%3EELIMINAR%3C/a%3E

y deberia ser:

http://localhost:7748/Usuario/Delete/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por las respuestas, pero ninguna funciono, buscando encontré la solución a mi problema que es:

```html
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Detalles" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "DATOS", new { id = item.PKDATOS })'">
 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Editar" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "DATOS", new { id = item.PKDATOS })'">
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Eliminar" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "DATOS", new { id = item.PKDATOS })'">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este codigo.

```
<input type="button" value="Go Somewhere Else" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

La URL que está generando es, luego de decodificarla:

```
http://localhost:9860/<a href=\"/Usuario/Delete/1\">ELIMINAR</a>
```

El problema es que `@Html.ActionLink` genera un tag `<a>`, si quieres solo la URL cámbialo por `@Html.Action` solamente.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,
el error lo tiene en q no haz colocado a q Accion y a q Controller vas ha ir forma correcta es esta:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" title="Edit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "EditController", new { id = item.id})'">
```

Edit es la accion  y EditController es el controlador a donde quiere ir (CotizacionController el sufijo Controller no es necesario).
gracias!!